# Serialize Flutter Widget

Tags: flutter, serialization, widget

Is there any way to serialize the Build layout of a stateless flutter widget and save it to a database?

I would like to design many simple Badge widgets and don‘t want to update the App each Time I have a new one.

I would like to save new widgets to a db instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Remote flutter widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/rfw) - may be the direction. It has mechanism for rendering widgets based on declarative UI descriptions that can be obtained & rendered at runtime.